# PHP Live Chat Message insert ( Live streaming Chat, not VideoID Comment )

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, livechat, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm actually building a PHP bot that reads the youtube live streaming chat, and store in a Database the message that contains a specific keyword wrote by the users during the livestream. All the logic is in place, what is missing is the feedback on chat when the bot is "triggered".
I looked everywhere but seams the PHP documentation is missing, if you look inside the PHP Classes there is the public function insert, but there is no example at all on how to use it? 
Someone know how to use it?
Should be something "simple" like: `$result = $youtube->liveChatMessages->Insert($args);` but I can't figure out on what args looks like.

[HERE](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/YouTube/Resource/LiveChatMessages.php) the only reference about the Insert method

Thanks to all for any suggestion on how to use it!

**17/06/2018 edit Working Example**

```
$liveChatMessage = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveChatMessage();
$liveChatSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveChatMessageSnippet();
$liveChatSnippet->setLiveChatId($liveChatID);
$liveChatSnippet->setType("textMessageEvent");
$messageDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveChatTextMessageDetails();
$messageDetails->setMessageText("Message to type in chat");
$liveChatSnippet->setTextMessageDetails($messageDetails);
$liveChatMessage->setSnippet($liveChatSnippet);
$videoCommentInsertResponse = $youtube->liveChatMessages->insert('snippet', $liveChatMessage);
```

Comment: Check the [google/google-api-php-client-services](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/YouTube/Resource/LiveChatMessages.php). It's accompanied with comments on how to use it. "The part parameter serves two purposes. It identifies the properties that the write operation will set as well as the properties that the API response will include. Set the parameter value to snippet."

Comment: @noogui the comment of the code in that page doesn't help so much a new people approaching the youtube-api. BTW, using the javascript example I successfully created a working code. 

For anyone is looking into an example, Added working code in the first message.